# PHP include call fails

Tags: php, function, include

I'm writing a series of web pages in which I want to modify the format in which a time-of-day is displayed. I've written a PHP function to do that, and the function works perfectly when the it is in the same file as the rest of the code. However, I want to do this conversion process in several related files, so I"d like to put the function in an external file that I can simply "include" where needed. TBut I can't get tghe "include" bit to work.

Here's the code I'm using for the inclusion process:

```
<?php
  include 'http://www.northcentralflaa.org/header.html';
  include 'http://www.northcentralflaa.org/d.sysadmin/f-time.php';
?>
```

The header file (in the first "include" line) shows up with no problem, but the f-time.php file is not brought in.

The error_log file tells me this:

> "[07-Jul-2016 11:12:03] PHP Warning:  include() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   'http://www.northcentralflaa.org/d.sysadmin/f-time.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home1/northce1/public_html/d.sysadmin/admin-portal.php on line 19"

This appears to be telling me - in "(include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/share/pear')" - that the system is looking for some files in a sub-directory that, as far as I know, does not exist. But, as I said, the first "include" statement works perfectly.

FWIW, I've also tried the HTML SSI inclusion process:

: `<!--#include file="http://www.northcentralflaa.org/d.sysadmin/f-time.php" -->`

(outside the php brackets, of course), and I've tried both processes using a relative path instead of absolue path, both with and without the leading dot-slant. I've checked my spelling of directory and file names. And even though the function works perfectly when written in the base web-page file, I've also tried commenting-out the entire function (in the f-time.php file) and importing only a line saying

```
echo "The file was imported";
```

Even that fails to show up. Any ideas where I can look further for resolution?

Comment: is that your own server? then you don't need a full-blown http request to load those files. that's massively inefficient, and forces php to do its own http requests in response to the http request that loaded the original script in the first place. And if they are remote, you do **NOT** want to load remote php files, because you'll be EXECUTING those scripts, and getting their output, not raw php code.

Comment: Also the page requires authentication so that can't work.

Comment: Marc B - No, this is not my own server. The files are on a server hundreds of miles away. Is there no way, then, to re-use a PHP function in multiple files without copying-and-pasting it into each file?

Comment: Lightness Races in Orbit - I'm not clear what you mean. I've just tried putting the function file in a publicly-available subdirectory and changing the include-statement to that effect, but still no joy. Of course, the main file is in a subdirectory that requires authentication, but I have had to provide that authentication just to see it and run the file that calls the include-statement. Can you clarify your meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix. I cannot fully understand why it works, but if I re-write that second include commend as

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/d.attic/f-time.php';
```

it works as expected. (The re-write was NOT required of the first include statement, which leaves me mystified.)

Answer (score 0):

include calls to localized filepaths, not URLs.

```
<?php
  include 'header.html';
  include 'd.sysadmin/f-time.php';
?>
```

Comment: I've tried that, as mentioned in my original posting. And no matter how I call the files, the call to the header file DOES work, every time, and the call to the f-time.php file FAILS every time.